# Ajax calling a java Rest API

Tags: java, ajax, rest

I am having ajax problems that I cannot figure out, and need some help... I am using Spring for my REST api and my ajax calls don't seem to work... I have searched the forums and haven't been able to find an answer:

My java Spring api is as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api")
public class RecentRestController {

    RecentService recentService;

    @Autowired
    public void PersonRestController(RecentService recentService) {
        this.recentService = recentService;
    }

    /**
     * Add recent lake, then get recently viewed lakes and users ordered by timestamp
     * @param handle
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "recent/weather/{auser}/{temp}/{windspeed}/{winddeg}/{laketag}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public RecentlyViewedList getRecentlyViewedLakes(@PathVariable String auser, @PathVariable Integer temp, 
            @PathVariable Integer windspeed, @PathVariable Integer winddeg, @PathVariable String laketag) {

        RecentlyViewedList rvl = recentService.getRecentlyViewedWeather(auser, temp, windspeed, winddeg, laketag);
        return rvl;
    }
```

When I use ajax to call this Java REST from ajax it doesn't seem to work.  My ajax call looks as follows from html/php:

```
new $Ajax.Request('http://localhost:8080/server/api/weahter/lake/' + agruments.auser + '/' + arguments.windspeed +'/' + arguments.winddeg + '/' + arguments.laketag, {
      type : "GET",
       //:url : recenturl,
       //cache : false,
       async : false,
       crossDomain: true,
       dataType : 'jsonp',
       //data: arguments,
       success : function(recent) {


           alert("SUCESS");
            var i=0;

            var lakecount = recent.lake.length;
            var usercount = recent.user.length;

            alert("lakecount:" + lakecount);
            alert("usercount:" + usercount);

       },
       error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
       }, 
    });
```

It never seems to work.  It never calls my REST api correct..  What am I doing incorrectly?

Something is wrong with how I calling my REST service..

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you are checking for a @GET request, the most obvious thing to do is to try to hit the API directly from a browser ( type in your URL field

```
http://localhost:8080/server/api/weahter/lake/' + agruments.auser + '/' + arguments.windspeed +'/' + arguments.winddeg + '/' + arguments.laketag
```

with the parameters resolved ).

Other thing you should be checking is that your context path is 'server' as that is where the URL is pointing.

Also you have and spelling error in the first parameter of the URL: 'agruments' instead of 'arguments'

Comment: Yeah, fixed the spelling error, but unless I hardcode the URL, it does not work.  When I add parameters with "/" between them it never hits the REST API.  I stumped..

Comment: When I try to hit it directly, it is also not working...It is quoting issue?  I have tried a POST with arguments as well, and that doesn't work...  If I hardcode the call it works find...  Argh

Comment: http://localhost:8080/server/api/recent/lake/nightstalker/3/3/3/TXFORK,works fine and I get back: the corrent JSON

Comment: Did you print the parameters? could some of them be null/undefined/etc?

Comment: Yes, they are not null or undefined.

Comment: Are you checking the browser console for errors? Could it be a Cross Domain issue? Is the service running on the same host:port as the server of the html?

Comment: I've just realized that http://localhost:8080/server/api/recent/lake/nightstalker/3/3/3/TXFORK has a 'recent' path part and http://localhost:8080/server/api/weahter/lake/' + agruments.auser... doesn't. Despite this, you could use a filter or a breakpoint in your application to check the url you're receiving. Also, are you checking the url which is being generated on your brower's console?

Comment: If I hard code the request it works... Once I build the request using variables it doesn't.  weird

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the request has recent in it.  What I cannot figure out is that if I build it manualy:

```
   url : 'http://localhost:8080/server/api/recent/lake/nightstalker/3/3/3/TXFORK'
```

it works.  But when I build it with variables, it does not.